# Why do columns in visualization chart y axis show General0,General25,... instead of 0,25,50,75,100?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I have a Google visualization dashboard that gets data from the query of a spreadsheet.

The column labels on the Y axis show:

```
General0, General25, General50, General75, General100
```

Instead of:

```
0,25,50,75,100
```

Does anyone know why this is?  I'm assuming it has something to do with the query. I attached the code and a picture of the chart.

Thanks! Brandon

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a bar chart,
      // passes in the data and draws it.
      
      function drawDashboard() {
         var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/a/sleschool.org/spreadsheets/d/1TRcHxsLuunRUPgn-i-h3OcVvh0TNp_VhJrNBI3ulMlA/edit#gid=0');
      
      query.setQuery('select A,B,C');
      
      query.send(handleQueryResponse);
      }

      function handleQueryResponse(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
          alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
          return;
        }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
        // Create a dashboard.
        
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        // Create a range slider, passing some options
        var scoreSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
            containerId: 'filter_div',
            options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'Score'
               }
        });
        
        var rtiFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'CategoryFilter', 
            containerId: 'rtifilter_div',
            options: {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'RTI','ui': { 'labelStacking': 'vertical','allowTyping': true,'allowMultiple': true
               }
        }});

        // Create a Column Bar chart, passing some options
        var columnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'ColumnChart',
            containerId: 'chart_div',
            options: {
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            legend: 'right',
            title: 'Summative Assessment Data',
               }
        });
        
        // Define a table
        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          chartType: 'Table',
          dataTable: data,
          containerId: 'table_div',
          options: {
          width: '400px'
               }
         });
       
        // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'ColumnChart',
        // so that the column chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.
        
        dashboard.bind([scoreSlider], [table, columnChart]);
        dashboard.bind([rtiFilter], [table, columnChart]);

        // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(data);
      }
      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
     <div id="dashboard_div">
    
     <h2>Summative Assessment Data</h2>
     
      <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
      <br />
     
      <div id="rtifilter_div"></div>
   
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="chart_div"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="table_div"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Chart![Whole Dashboard]

Comment: Not sure why is not being set automatically, but by formatting the columns in the sheet as Number by going to Format>Number>More Formats, i selected the first option so the numbers keep the same (and not 92.00) and then the chart was rendered without "General". hope it helps

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: I thought that it worked. But it doesn't seem to stick. Did you highlight the numbers first? Thanks.

Comment: I selected the whole column and then applied the format

Comment: @Gerardo can you forumulate the same in an answer, so this can be closed?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this would be to format the columns in the sheet as Number(for some reason this is not being set automatically).

By going to Format>Number>More Formats, select the first option so the numbers keep the same (and not 92.00) and then the chart will be rendered without "General". Its better to select the whole column and then applied the format.